# Select one row instead multiple with same id and different value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have one question does anyone know how I can got this from SQL table

```
id | value1 | value2 | value3
1       1      null     null
1       1       2       null
1       1       5        6
2       2      null     null
2       3       5       null
3       7      null     null
3       6       0        8
```

result should be

```
id | value1 | value2 | value3
1       1       5        6
2       3       5       null
3       6       0        8
```

edit: result should be rows where i have more item (value1, value2, value3) filled

edit2: table above is result of some previous query. I we have two or more rows with same value fields filled then I should get all of this rows but if not then I should get only row with more data field. Importance of values go from right to left

note. I use MSSQL

Comment: Can you tell us how to chose a value1/value2/value3 when an id has several different such values?

Comment: I *think* you question has been downvoted for two reasons.  Firstly it doesn't include your attempt at writing this query.  Secondly, as is clear from the comments in @jarlh's answer, the question doesn't fully explain what you are after.  If you edit this question it will help others who find themselves with a similar problem in the future.

Comment: @destination-data you're right. I made mistake when I post the question because I didn't explain all use cases. I had updated post

Answer (score 2):

Do a `GROUP BY id` to get each id only once. Use `MIN` (or perhaps `MAX`) to pick one value1 etc for an id.

```
select id,
       min(value1) as value1,
       max(value2) as value2,
       min(value3) as value3
from tablename
group by id
```

**Edit:**

Use a common table expression (cte), where you also count the number of non-null
values for each row. Return all cte rows that has max count for that id.

```
with cte as
(
select t.*, case when value1 is null then 0 else 1 end +
            case when value2 is null then 0 else 1 end +
            case when value3 is null then 0 else 1 end as valcount
from tablename
)
select t1.id, t1.value1, t1.value2, t1.value3
from cte t1
where t1.valcount = (select max(valcount) from cte t2 where t1.id = t2.id)
```

Comment: Maybe need to use `MAX`?

Comment: @Devart, seems like MIN sometimes, and MAX sometimes. (E.g. id 3 has value1 7, but OP wants 6. I.e max not used there.)

Comment: I don't need to merge rows with same id. I need only row who have more items (val1, val2,val3) filled

Comment: @DavorDumeljic, and if two rows have the same number of items filled?

Comment: @jarlh then I can get all of them (more then one row in result)

Comment: @DavorDumeljic, alright, will be back in a while. Stay tuned!

Comment: @jarlh what is t t1 t2 in your query above

Comment: Table aliases. Since I use the same table twice, I have to give them different (temporary) names.

Comment: @jarlh this table above is result of some query before. Than mean I should this result save in some temp table and then use it couple times?